# React app starting using the wrong network adapter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, networking, webpack, windows-10

**Update**

*Everything below this update is from when I hadn't narrowed down the issue to the wrong network adapted being used. That being said:*

My React app created using Create React App, run using `npm start`, uses my Virtual Box network adapted, instead of my WLAN adapter, meaning that I cannot connect my app using devices on my network. How can I make my app use the correct network adapter? I would prefer not to have to disable the Virtual box adapter, since it is useful.

---

My React app cannot be viewed on devices on the same network, despite the output from `npm start` (below). The browser displays `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view untitled in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.56.1:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

- I have tried running `npm start` from within WebStorm, and from
  Windows Powershell
- Node.js is allowed through the firewall
- I am using a fresh install of Windows 10 (no weird settings under the hood)
- I have tried connecting from 3 different devices on my local network, using `192.168.56.1:3000`
- I have restarted my computer twice
- I have tried all of this with my host computer's firewall turned off
- I have replicated all of this with a blank project created with Create React App
- I have tried port 4000 as well

Any help is obviously much appreciated.

**Update**

On my Windows 10 laptop, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, but on the other two devices I have tested with, I get ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED (an iPad and an Android phone, both on the same network as the host computer).

Comment: check if the port is allowed on the firewall

Comment: Tried adding a few Windows Firewall inbound rules, including allowing all ports for all protocols. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where `npm start` choose the wrong ip/network adapter for the LAN network on Windows.

The IP is resolved inside `react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js:preapreUrls`
by calling the method `address.ip` which is implemented inside `address/lib/address.js`

On Windows, They use the first interface IPv4 they find which is the cause of the problem.

The easiest way to "fix" it would be to set the HOST environment variable which will bypass the interface lookup all together.

--

A quick "fix" the interface lookup would be to modify the line [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js#L46)

From

`lanUrlForConfig = address.ip();`

to

`lanUrlForConfig = address.ip("<Name of your interface>");`;